# Background image with background size: cover doesn’t fit my background image completely

Tags: image, image-processing, background-image, cover, background-size

I tried setting  the background size to cover but still the particular spot I want doesn’t show as everything still looks zoomed in. How do I make a particular area show as background image even when the background size is set to cover.

I tried setting the background size to cover, thinking this would make it fit  perfectly but still it doesn’t work, but it worked for another picture.

Comment: [mre] required.